# Nested for-loop with delay on each iteration in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to implement a nested for-loop with a delay in each iteration.

So far I've came up with something like this

```
var maxLoops = 10 ;
var counter = 0;
var counter2 = counter;

var maxLoops = 10 ;
var counter = 0;
var counter2 = counter;

(function nNext() {

  if (counter == maxLoops) return
  counter2 = counter - 1;

  setTimeout(() => (function next() {

     if (counter2 >= maxLoops) return;

     setTimeout(() => {
          console.log( "Nester counter :" + counter2);
          counter2++
          next()
     }, 100)

  })(), 1)
  counter++;
  nNext();

})();
```

Yet it doesn't work properly. I am trying to make a visual representation of a bubble sort and I need this delay so as to see each step which is kind of impossible if array sorts immediately without this delay. Is it actually possible to implement such thing? Or maybe there is a better way to do this?

Comment: Define "doesn't work properly"?

Comment: You're immediately invoking `nNext` and then invoking it again recursively without delay. Is that really what you want?

Comment: Also, in the outer `setTimeout`, you're passing an arrow function that has a body that immediately invokes a function named `next`. Why? Seems like the arrow function can just be removed, as well as the immediate invocation of `next`, and just pass `function next() {...}`.

Comment: *"...which is kind of impossible if array sorts immediately without this delay"*. You're not trying to delay the actual bubble sort, are you? I think if you want a visual representation, I'd just record the steps by pushing data to an array during the sort, and then asynchronously iterate through that to show it visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The structure you've got seems a bit complex, this should accomplish what you're looking for:

```js
var maxLoops = 10,
    counter = 0,
    counter2 = 0;

function outerNext() {
  if (counter == maxLoops) return;
  counter2 = counter - 1
  innerNext()
}

function innerNext() {
  if (counter2 >= maxLoops) {
    outerNext()
  }
  else {
    counter2++;
    console.log("Nester counter :" + counter2);
    setTimeout(innerNext, 500)
  }
}
outerNext()
```